# BlackBerry OS 10 development using Titanium

Tags: titanium, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10, titanium-modules

I am working on BlackBerry OS 10.I am trying to develop application using **Titanium** studio. I have added BlackBerry plugin and downloaded and installed BB NDK and following same procedure as shown in the link : [BlackBerry Development Using Titanium](http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/bb/) .

Set up is ok but when I am trying to create new project an error is shown as:**Unable to create new project.
Available platforms for SDK version undefined:**

I was guessing that I have given wrong path for BB NDK. But I have tried all possible ways. Still I am getting this error.

Please help me to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Titanium Studio >> Preferences:
[image]

Make sure the url points to where you downloaded your BB NDK.

Comment: Thnx for your reply..I have already try that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Titanium is looking for a filename that doesn't exist.
You can fix it with a symbolic link:

( In /Application/Momentics.app ):

```
$ ln -s target_10_2_0_1155 install

$ ln -s bbndk-env_10_2_0_1155.sh bbndk-env.sh
```

For a video walkthrough [see here.](http://blog.codexlabs.com/blog/2013/09/setting-up-blackberry-10-for-titanium-studio/)